# Merge trees on equal nodes

Tags: java

I have two trees for example:

```html
                                      <example>
   root           root2                  root after merge
     A0            A0                        A0
     |              |                        |
     A1             A1                       A1
    / \            /  \                  /  /   \  \  
   A2 A3          A4  A5               A2 A3   A4  A5
```

my class Node: with all its getter and setter:

```
public class Node {
    private String data;
    private Node parent;
    private List<Node> children;
    public Node(String data) {
        this.data = data;
        parent = null;
        children = new ArrayList<Node>(); //Empty list of children  
    }
}
```

this code what I tried but the execution not correct it is duplicate A1

```
private static void CompareTree(Node root2) {
    if(root==null) {
        root=root2;
    }
    else  {
        for (Node child : root.getChildren()) {
            for ( Node child1: root2.getChildren()){
                if( child.equals(child1)) 
                    // CompareTree(child1);
                    child.addChild(child1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone can help me I would be very grateful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is supposed to happen in the case that there are no common elements ? what assumptions can we make ?

Comment: mm...print("There is no similarity")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One major problem is how you compare nodes: `n1.equals(n2)`. But you never overwrote the `equals`-method in `Node`, so the default provided by `java.lang.Object` will be used, which behaves in the following way:

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-)

This means that the comparison won't look at `data` (which is the relevant field, I assume), but simply compare the references. You need to override `equals` in `Node` in the following way to provide the expected behavior for `equals`:

```
class Node{
    ... // variables and constructor

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        return (o != null) && (o instanceof Node) && (data.equals(((Node) o).data);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return Objects.hash(data);
    }
}
```

(Note that the above implementation assumes that `Node#data` will never be `null`. If this is the case, rewrite the code accordingly!)

The merge-operation itself:
For a `static` method I'd recommend using one parameter for each `Node` and work in the following way, since a recursive approach is the simplest:

```
static void merge(Node a, Node b){
    List<Node> toMerge = new ArrayList<>(a.getChildren()).retainAll(b.getChildren());
    List<Node> toAdd = new ArrayList<>(b.getChildren()).removeAll(a.getChildren());

    for(Node n : toMerge)
        merge(n, b.getChildren().get(b.getChildren().indexOf(n)));

    for(Node n : toAdd)
        a.addChild(n.deepCopy());
}

class Node{
    ... //variables, constructor, equals, etc.

    public Node deepCopy(){
        Node n = new Node(data);

        for(Node c : children)
            n.addChild(c.deepCopy());

        return n;
    }
}
```

The above code works in the following way:
`toMerge` contains all child-nodes from `b` for which a child-node with equivalent `data` exists in `a` (set intersection), `toAdd` contains all child-nodes of `b` for which no child-node with equivalent `data` exists in `a` (set difference). These two sets are complementary, so no nodes get lost and none get added. For all nodes that need to be merged `merge` is applied recursively to the node in `a` and it's equivalent in `b`. For all nodes that only occur in `b`, an deep copy of that node is added as child of `a` (a deep-copy is copy of the entire tree-structure starting from a specific node).